# What does it take for 220V AC to shock you?

Tags: current, ac, shock

After heavy rains, we had severe water logging in our lawn and front yard.

My brother got an AC submersible pump from the market, small thing (*sits on the palm of my hand*), not great flow rates (*maybe 4-6 ltrs per minute*,) nothing fancy (*the cheap kind which when you buy and ask the shopkeeper for "warranty" he just stares at you like that word has personally hurt him*.) The cable it came with was short so we made a joint with a longer cable and just put insulation tape on it. Now when I discovered this apparatus and saw that the joint was submerged in water and that we were often stepping into the water without getting shocked, it surprised me.

What's going on here? Did we insulate it so well that not even a drop of water is coming in touch with bare metal wiring, or is something else to thank?

Comment: the electricity has a better place to go than through you. you are probably getting some of it, just not enough to even notice. if your foot is 1 ohm and the water around it is 0.1ohm, then you're only going to get ~22v.

Comment: It's electrocution just waiting to happen (what you have described). I don't understand why you bought a submersible pump with no warranty and joined the cable at a point that is under water. I hope you have residual current breakers on your circuits.

Comment: thanks @dandavis, perhaps that explains.

Comment: @Andyaka In my defense I didn't do it, but I'm going to get rid of it, promptly. Tell me one thing though, if the submersible is under water, wouldn't it also have exposed points even if the joint is above water? Never opened a submersible, don't know how its wired.

Comment: A submersible pump is designed to operate underwater so it will have been designed to keep it away from anything electrical. If you need to join the cable you can get connectors also designed for use underwater (rated at IP68 or better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once as a teenager I decided to stick two exposed live wires into a glass of water to see what would happen. I was disappointed to find that not a lot happened.<sup>A</sup> 
Freshwater as is, is not a great conductor, so two live wires inserted don't produce anything fun. Naturally, I added some salt, at which point I started to see some bubbling at the wires, but still not the drama I'd been hoping for. It's quite possible that your wiring has been running a small amount of current through the water all this time unnoticed.

Let's assume that the insulating isn't so incredible as to be completely watertight. There is a path between the two wires through the water, note the electricity is going to follow the path of least resistance, ie that's the water directly between the joints.
If you then step in the water somewhere away from the connector, the electricity isn't going to flow through you. If you consider the distance between the wires is going to be very short, maybe a few CM, the path to flow through your foot is going to add several extra cm of water, just to go through your foot, before flowing back to the other wire. In this case, it's doesn't really matter how resistive your foot is, because the water between you and the wires already represents much more resistance.<sup>B</sup>

In order to be shocked, you have to present a resistance to the electricity similar to the current path. It's like adding parallel resistors, if the current path is X Ohm, and you add 100X with your foot, you won't get any real shock. If you add 4X, you get a quarter of the current. 
You could do this by sticking your foot in between the wire joints, now the path through the water has to flow around your foot increasing it, so your foot represents a shorter path most likely.

In this case, there's also Earth to consider. The yard I presume is dirt/on the ground, so there's also a path through the water to Earth. If you have some kind of RCD and it's not tripping, this does tell you something about how much current is flowing to Earth through the water. In the same way, if you put your foot between the wires and Earth you might get a shock. Or if you were to touch something metal with a hand that was earthed, like a copper pipe, you might present a stronger path to Earth and get a shock that way, through the heart, and therefore possibly fatal.

For anyone's benefit, not just the OP who said they're fixing this, don't misinterpret the possibly low likelihood of a shock with safety. You should look for ways to extend the wires that are designed to be submerged.

A) I'm not recommending, in any way, playing with live wires.
B) I'm slightly misrepresenting the resistance of water in this case. Resistance is a bit more complicated than that, but seems out of the scope of the question. Assuming proportional to length works well enough for the explanation.